# **Redundant conformance of 'FlickrPhotosViewController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'**

Tags: xcode, swift

I am following this (http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) tutorial, and now i am

getting this error :

**Redundant conformance of 'FlickrPhotosViewController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'**

So i have this code over here :

```
extension FlickrPhotosViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

//1
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return searches.count
}

//2
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searches[section].searchResults.count
}

//3
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Configure the cell
    return cell
```

So what does this error mean?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Redundant conformance" means that you are specifying `extension FlickrPhotosViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource`, but this isn't necessary because `FlickrPhotosViewController`'s superclass already provides a `UICollectionViewDataSource` conformance.

You can just use `extension FlickrPhotosViewController` instead.